# Fatal error when using one module's controller action code in another module

Tags: magento-1.8

We are allowing guest to create an account with help of below function

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('productlike/index/create', 
 array('_secure'=>(!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS']==='on'))) 
  ?>" method="post" id="ajaxlogin-create-form">
```

> controllers

app/code/local/Outthink/ProductLike/controllers - Indexcontroller.php

```
class Outthink_ProductLike_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action  {
public function createAction(){  }
}
```

we are using same function code in another module as below, but its not working

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('example/Amasty/create1', 
     array('_secure'=>(!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS']==='on'))) 
      ?>" method="post" id="ajaxlogin-create-form">
```

app/code/local/Amasty/Example/controllers - Amastycontrollers.php

```
class Amasty_Example_AmastyController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {
public function create1Action(){  }
    }
```

Is this right way ? I dont want to rewrite same controller action because i need some other feature with the functions.

> update

Fatal error `Call to undefined method Amasty_Example_AmastyController::_getCustomer()` in line `$customer = $this->_getCustomer();`

```
public function create1Action()

    {
        // Clear the messages each time we call it
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getMessages(true);

        $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');

        if ($session->isLoggedIn()) {
            return;
        }

        $session->setEscapeMessages(true); // prevent XSS injection in user input
        if (!$this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            return;
        }

        $result = array(
            'success' => false
        );

        $customer = $this->_getCustomer();

        try {
            $errors = $this->_getCustomerErrors($customer);

            if (empty($errors)) {
                if (version_compare(Mage::getVersion(),"1.9.1.0",">="))
                {
                    // Only from 1.9.1.0
                    $customer->cleanPasswordsValidationData();
                }
                $customer->save();
                Mage::dispatchEvent('customer_register_success',
                    array('account_controller' => $this, 'customer' => $customer)
                );
                $result['redirect'] = $this->_successProcessRegistration($customer);
                $customerId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
                 $productId=$this->getRequest()->getPost('product_id');
                    $likeProduct=Mage::getModel('productlike/productlike')->getCollection()
                        ->addFieldToSelect('fav_id')
                        ->addFieldToFilter('product_id',$productId)
                        ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',$customerId)->load();
                     /*


                    */
                $result['success'] = true;
            } 

        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {

        } 

        catch (Exception $e) {

           // $result['error'] = $this->__('Cannot save the customer.');
        }

        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
    }
```

Comment: try this `example/amasty/create1` instead of this `example/Amasty/create1`

Comment: tried now, no luck.....

Comment: If you hit the url directly in browser does that work?

Comment: Try $block->getUrl('example/amasty/create1')

Comment: @KingshukDeb i tried as `http://1234.com/example/amasty/create1` , it gave blank page......

Comment: @KishanPatadia tried , but not worked for me....

Comment: @raj thats ok i think. Because you have not written anything inside that function. Try to print something there and check if its calling that function. If its working then it should work inside the form too.

Comment: Can you please provide the <frontName> in the config.xml of Amasty's example modules? You should pass the string in getUrl('frontname/amasty/create1').

Comment: @NasirPerwaiz we have `<frontName>example</frontName>` and we are passing `example/Amasty/create1`,

Comment: @raj when you click on the register button does the execution go inside that function or not?...It should go. And as its printing inside the function i guess its going inside that function. Now the `customer registration` working or not that your code issue. Thats not related to the question.

Comment: @KingshukDeb it is printing only when i tried with browser url as `http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/example/amasty/create1/id/19960/`, but when i click on `register/submit`, it displayed like : http://prnt.sc/f0k8zr

Comment: @raj why dont you just put `echo'hiii'; exit;` inside the function in the very first line. And click the `register` button then check in `network` if its printing.

Comment: I think the routing is perfect. Try to echo on the first line and then exit as suggested by Kingshuk Deb.

Comment: Dont send us network images. You need to click on it and check whats the response. Routing is perfect. Debug your code inside it.

Comment: @KishanPatadia i am using same  code in another controller, but there it worked fine, response : http://prnt.sc/f0kkhl , thanks for time, i will try....

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57681/discussion-on-question-by-raj-fatal-error-when-using-one-modules-controller-act).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please paste missing functions code in your controller file. The code is in other file.